# How to specify the font used for word doc exported using pandoc?

Tags: ms-word, markdown, pandoc

Rendering a microsoft word document using pandoc.  The font seems to default to ***Calibri*** for headings and ***Cambri*** for body text.  Goal is to have the file use Arial or Times roman fonts.

I don't want to touch/edit/have anything to do with the file in word.

How can I set the font that will be used in Word™ from either the multi-markdown source or in the call to [pandoc](http://pandoc.org)?

Pandoc command:

```
pandoc -s my_markdown.txt -o whycambriafont.docx
```

This question: [pandoc-generated docx misses italic variables in equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357899/pandoc-generated-docx-misses-italic-variables-in-equations) shows a way to edit the font styles by creating a zip and then editing the style files, but is a kludge.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can supply a reference.docx file with the [--reference-doc option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--reference-doc) to pandoc which acts sort of like a template.

1. Generate a file with `echo 'hello word' | pandoc -o reference.docx` or similar.
2. Change the font in the style. Either by opening the file in Word, changing the style and saving it, or alternatively opening it for example with `vim`:

   - Rename the `reference.docx` to `reference.zip`
   - `vim reference.zip` and select `reference/theme/theme1.xml`
   - find and change `Calibri` to `Arial`
   - save and rename zip back to docx
3. Profit: use with `pandoc --reference-doc reference.docx`

See also [Defining-custom-DOCX-styles-in-LibreOffice-(and-Word)](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Defining-custom-DOCX-styles-in-LibreOffice-(and-Word)).