# Change size of a section of pandoc text for docx rendering

Tags: r, pandoc, quarto

I'm trying to reduce the size of *a section* of text within a qmd document that needs rendering in **docx**.

I tried using a styled div:

```
---
title: "Test"
format: docx
---

The main text will be normal-sized.

::: {style="font-size: 10pt;"}
This block of text should be sized 10pt.
:::
```

**Observed output**:

[image: Observed output]

---

**Intended outptut**:

[image]

Of note, my code works well in html.

Is there another way of doing this with a docx output?

Answer (score 0):

The styling process for docx is a little different: one needs to create a "reference doc", set the styles in that doc and apply it with

```yaml
---
format:
  docx:
    reference-doc: my-styled-reference.docx
---
```

See [How to specify the font used for word doc exported using pandoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34600141/2425163) and [How do I add custom formatting to docx files generated in Pandoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70513062/2425163) for more details on this process.